# Make scrollable sidebar with tooltips using Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, overflow, tailwind-css

I have a sidebar made with Tailwind CSS and I'd like to make it scrollable. My problem is, that when you hover over an entry in the list, a small text label should be displayed next to the entry, outside of the sidebar (shown below).

[image: A Picture of my Sidebar. It has some icons from Fontawesome, and if you hover over one of the Items, there is text displayed next to the Sidebar]

When I use `overflow-y-scroll` it scrolls fine on the **Y**-axis, but instead of displaying the hover text next to the sidebar, it makes the sidebar scrollable on the **X**-axis and basically hides the text.

My Sidebar JSX:

```
    <aside className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-screen w-16 m-0 flex flex-col bg-red-800 text-white shadow-lg">
        <div className='overflow-y-scroll'>
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={0} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={1} />
            <SidebarIcon text="asdf" icon={2} />
        </div>
    </aside>
```

My SidebarIcon component:

```
    const SidebarIcon = function ({ icon, text}) {

        let icons = [
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('display')} className="w-[28px] h-[28px]" size='28'/>,         // Desktop  0
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('laptop')} className="w-[28px] h-[28px]" size='28'/>,          // Laptop   1
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('mobile-screen')} className="w-[28px] h-[28px]" size='28'/>    // Mobile   2
        ]
        
        return (
            <div className={`sidebar-icon group shrink-0`}>
                { icons[icon] }

                <span class='sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100'> { text } </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And at last the CSS for the icons:

```css
    .sidebar-icon {
        @apply bg-red-900 text-gray-50;
        @apply relative flex items-center justify-center;
        @apply h-12 w-12 mx-auto my-2;
        @apply shadow-lg rounded-lg;
        @apply transition-all duration-150 ease-linear;
        @apply hover:bg-gray-800 hover:text-red-800;
    }

    .sidebar-tooltip{
      @apply absolute w-auto p-2 m-2 min-w-max left-14;
      @apply rounded-md shadow-md;
      @apply text-white bg-gray-900;
      @apply text-xs font-bold;
      @apply transition-all duration-100 scale-0 origin-left
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a width on your wrapper `div`? For example: `<div className='w-16 overflow-y-scroll'>`.

Comment: Sadly yes, and I also tried adding the `overflow-y-scroll` class to the `<aside/>` Tag with the same result :/

Comment: I'm sure this is problem with absolute stuff, can i see the `sidebar-tooltip` css?

Comment: This is a CSS problem with `overflow` and not specific to Tailwind. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue

Comment: @AhmadShiddiq Thanks for commenting, added the CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are applying the scroll property to the entire `list` of `SidebarIcon` component.

And in the `SidebarIcon` on hover you are scalling up the icon. Basically you are hiding it and then making it visible when hovered.

Because of which even the `tooltip` is inside the `scroll`.
Which is leading to this undefined behavior.

To overcome this, I prefer you use [Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tooltips/) as it is preferred in the tailwindcss's official documentation.

And follow the below links for the installation and setup of `Tailwind CSS Tooltip - Flowbite`

- https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/
- https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/

Hope it helps !

Comment: Great Idea, I'll probably use flowbite in the future, sadly their Tooltip has the same effect as my tooltip :/